# Can anyone assist to speed up this code to delete rows based on cells in a list?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet of data of between 30k to 50k lines with approximately 30 categories, that need to have some of these categories removed based on text in a varying list of cells on a separate page.
The data is on a tab titled "Projects" and the varying list of Categories to be removed is on another tab "wsGraphs" in cells starting at Q31. Typically with 30000 lines and 8 categories to find and remove takes anywhere from 10 to 20 minutes to complete! Any help with speeding up the process will be much appreciated.

```
Dim Firstrow As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim lrow As Long

Set wsGraphs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Graphs")

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Projects")

    'Set the first and last row to loop through
    Firstrow = 4
    Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Loop from Lastrow to Firstrow (bottom to top)
    For lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1

        'Check the values in column A.
        With .Cells(lrow, "A")
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Value, wsGraphs.Range("Q31:Q" & xLR), 0)) Then .EntireRow.Delete
           ' End If
        End With
    Next lrow
End With
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72141217/faster-method-to-delete-a-range-of-rows-other-that-using-union

Answer (score 1):

This might be quite a bit quicker. Load the values into memory and then decide what you're keeping there.

```vb
Sub QuickDelete()
    Dim origData As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Graphs")
        Set origData = Intersect( _
            .UsedRange, _
            .Range(.Range("A4"), .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).EntireRow)
    End With
    
    Dim maxCols As Long
    maxCols = origData.Columns.Count
    
    Dim origVals() As Variant
    origVals = origData.Formula
    
    Dim keepRows As New Collection
    
    Dim maxRows As Long
    maxRows = UBound(origVals, 1)
    
'   Select data
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To maxRows
        If IsError(origVals(i, 1)) Then keepRows.Add i
    Next i
    
'   Copy data
    Dim newVals() As Variant
    ReDim newVals(1 To keepRows.Count, 1 To maxCols)
    
    Dim j As Long
    Dim cpRow As Long
    For i = 1 To keepRows.Count
        cpRow = keepRows(i)
        For j = 1 To maxCols
            newVals(i, j) = origVals(cpRow, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    
'   Clear old data and paste new
    origData.ClearContents
    origData.Resize(keepRows.Count, maxCols).Formula = newVals
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks SSlinky, but I keep getting a Subscript out of range error after the first "Next i". Also, just to clarify, the list of items to check for is contained on Sheets("Graphs") and the bulk data to be checked and deleted is on ("Projects"). Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

### Delete Criteria Rows Efficiently Using `AutoFilter`

[image]

```vb
Sub DeleteCriteriaRows()

    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Delete Criteria Rows"
    
    Const SRC_NAME As String = "Graphs"
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "Q31"
    Const DST_NAME As String = "Projects"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "A3"
    Const DST_CRIT_COL As Long = 1
    Const DST_FLAG_STRING As String = "!|!"

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = DictSingleColumnRange(wb, SRC_NAME, SRC_FIRST_CELL)
    If dict Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        
    Dim fRows As Long: fRows = DeleteMultiCriteriaRows( _
        wb, DST_NAME, DST_FIRST_CELL, DST_CRIT_COL, dict, DST_FLAG_STRING)
        
    If fRows > 0 Then
        MsgBox fRows & " row" & IIf(fRows = 1, "", "s") & " deleted.", _
            vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    End If
    
End Sub

Function DictSingleColumnRange( _
    ByVal wb As Workbook, _
    ByVal WorksheetName As String, _
    ByVal FirstCell As String) _
As Object
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Single Column Range To Dictionary"
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(WorksheetName)
    If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData
    
    Dim rg As Range, rCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range(FirstCell)
        Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If Not lCell Is Nothing Then
            rCount = lCell.Row - .Row + 1
            Set rg = .Resize(rCount)
        End If
    End With
    
    If rg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No data found!", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Dim Data()
    
    If rCount = 1 Then
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
    Else
        Data = rg.Value
    End If
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim r As Long, rString As String
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        rString = CStr(Data(r, 1))
        If Len(rString) > 0 Then dict(rString) = Empty
    Next r
    
    If dict.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Only blank cells found!", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Set DictSingleColumnRange = dict

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

Function DeleteMultiCriteriaRows( _
    ByVal wb As Workbook, _
    ByVal WorksheetName As String, _
    ByVal FirstCell As String, _
    ByVal CriteriaColumn As Long, _
    ByVal CriteriaDictionary As Object, _
    Optional ByVal FlagString As String = "!|!") _
As Long
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Delete Multi-Criteria Rows"
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(WorksheetName)
    If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Dim rg As Range
    
    With ws.Range(FirstCell)
        Set rg = Intersect(.EntireRow.Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1), _
            ws.UsedRange)
    End With
    
    If rg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No data found.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = rg.Columns.Count
        
    If rCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Only headers found.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' Flag criteria column.
    
    Dim fRows As Long, WasFlagged As Boolean
    
    With rg.Resize(rCount).Offset(1)
        With rg.Columns(CriteriaColumn)
            Dim Data(): Data = .Value
            Dim r As Long
            For r = 1 To rCount
                If CriteriaDictionary.Exists(CStr(Data(r, 1))) Then
                    Data(r, 1) = FlagString
                    fRows = fRows + 1
                    WasFlagged = True
                End If
            Next r
            If WasFlagged Then .Value = Data
        End With
    End With
    
    If Not WasFlagged Then
        MsgBox "No criteria found.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Function
    End If
        
    ' Expand the range by one column to hold an ascending integer sequence.
    
    cCount = cCount + 1
    Set rg = rg.Resize(, cCount)
    
    ' Delete rows and clean up.
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    With rg.Resize(rCount).Offset(1)
        
        ' Write an ascending integer sequence to the added column.
        .Columns(cCount).Value = ws.Evaluate("ROW(1:" & rCount & ")")
        ' Sort by the criteria column to end up with a single filtered area.
        .Sort .Columns(CriteriaColumn), xlAscending, , , , , , xlNo
    
        ' Delete filtered rows.
        rg.AutoFilter CriteriaColumn, FlagString
        Dim dfrg As Range: Set dfrg = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        ws.AutoFilterMode = False
        dfrg.Delete xlShiftUp
        
        ' Sort by the added column to restore initial order.
        .Sort .Columns(cCount), xlAscending, , , , , , xlNo
        ' Clear the added column.
        .Columns(cCount).ClearContents
    
    End With

    DeleteMultiCriteriaRows = fRows

ProcExit:
    If Not Application.ScreenUpdating Then Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

Comment: Hi VBasic2008, Your code nearly gets there but fails near the end with a '1004' "Cant move cells in a filtered range or table".

Comment: Exactly, which line throws the error? It's hard to believe that it is line `dfrg.Delete xlShiftUp` or any line after, since I have just turned off the auto filter with `ws.AutoFilterMode = False`. If your data is in an Excel table, then you should have mentioned that. Out-comment the line `On Error GoTo ClearError` in `DeleteMultiCriteriaRows` to let VBA highlight the exact row.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That's exactly where it fails and jumps to ClearError: I think I have made an error in not stating that the data is in fact in a table. Would that make a difference to your code?

Comment: Excel tables (structured tables) are handled differently. They are easier to work with. They are recognized in the code by the word `ListObject` e.g. `Dim lo As ListObject: Set lo = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").ListOjbect("Table1")`. So next time either mention it or have `ListObject` in your code. There are too many changes necessary so I'm throwing in the towel. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Only run the delete once by using a `Union`.. something like this.... (I didn't test)

```
Dim Firstrow As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim lrow As Long

Set wsGraphs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Graphs")

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Projects")

'Set the first and last row to loop through
Firstrow = 4
Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

dim killRange as range
For lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1

        'Check the values in column A.
        With .Cells(lrow, "A")
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Value, wsGraphs.Range("Q31:Q" & xLR), 0)) Then
    if killRange is nothing then 
           set killRange = .entireRow
     else
           set killRange = Union(KillRange,.EntireRow)

            End If
        End With
    Next lrow
End With

if not KillRange is Nothing then
       killRange.Delete
End if
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, another way is something like this :

```
Sub test()
startTimer = Timer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim rgCrit As Range: Dim cell As Range: Dim rgU As Range

With Sheets("Graphs")
    Set rgCrit = .Range("Q31", .Range("Q31").End(xlDown))
End With

For Each cell In rgCrit
    With Sheets("Projects").Columns(1)
        If Not .Find(cell.Value) Is Nothing Then
        .Replace cell.Value, True, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
        If rgU Is Nothing Then Set rgU = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical) Else Set rgU = Union(rgU, .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical))
        .Replace True, cell.Value, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
        End If
    End With
Next

rgU.Select
'rgU.EntireRow.Delete

MsgBox Timer - startTimer

End Sub
```

rgCrit is the range of the varying list of Categories to be removed, starting from cell Q31 to whatever row in sheets Graphs.

The sub doesn't loop to each cell in column A of sheet Projects, but loop to each cell in rgCrit to get all rows in sheet Projects column A which has value of the looped cell as rgU variable.

After the loop finish, it select the rgU so you can check if the rows to be removed are in the selection.

If you found out that the selection is correct, then you can remove the `rgU.select` line and use the `rgU.entirerow.delete`

Not so sure though if this kind of code can give you faster process.