# Iterating through all cells in a Range to cut all Rows with Blank values?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and I have been trying for a few days now to iterate through all available rows, which I'm getting with "Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Select" to then iterate through the cells to then cut to somewhere else all rows that contain at least one empty cell.

It's been already a few days of research using the code from similar macros to understand and get the result I need, and I feel like I am really close with the snippet below, however I always get an error at some point that due to my low knowledge, I'm unable to properly understand and find a workaround:

```
Sub CutRowsWithEmptyCells()

Dim wsIn As Worksheet, wsout As Worksheet
Dim MyRange, myCell

Set wsIn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Customer Data")
Set wsout = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Incomplete Data")

Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Select


Set MyRange = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Select

For Each myCell In MyRange

    If Active.cell.Value = "" Then
    lrowOut = wsout.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cut wsout.Cells(lrowOut, 1)

End If
Next myCell

End Sub
```

Right now I'm getting an error on the "Set MyRange" line, I have tried several different variations but I can't figure it out. I also tried using the "Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Select" directly in the For Each as the "In" Value but it's also a type mismatch.

Could someone explain what is wrong with the code above and why?

Edit = I just realised I haven't "Dim lrowOut", I just reused this code from a similar macro, I just want to know what's wrong with the general logic, I think it wouldn't work neither if I create a "Dim lrowOut as Long" as I already tried in a different attempt. Sorry!

Comment: Hi, in which worksheet are you trying to iterate through? Also, you should always avoid using `Select` and `ActiveCell`

Comment: In this case it's the "Customer Data" ws. Would I need to say something like

For Each myCell In MyRange.wsIn ?

Answer (score 1):

- `Select` is a method of Range object, it can't be used in `Set`
- The result of `wsIn.Range("A1").CurrentRegion` may have multiple columns, you'd better use a nested For loop
- Deleting rows all at once will be more efficient

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub CutRowsWithEmptyCells()
    Dim wsIn As Worksheet, wsout As Worksheet
    Dim MyRange, myCell, lrowOut As Long
    Dim rowRange As Range, dataRange As Range
    Set wsIn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Customer Data")
    Set wsout = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Incomplete Data")
    Set MyRange = wsIn.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    For Each rowRange In MyRange.Rows
        For Each myCell In rowRange.Cells
            If myCell.Value = "" Then
                lrowOut = wsout.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
                myCell.EntireRow.Copy wsout.Cells(lrowOut, 1)
                If dataRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set dataRange = myCell
                Else
                    Set dataRange = Application.Union(dataRange, myCell)
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next myCell
    Next rowRange
    If Not dataRange Is Nothing Then dataRange.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

---

The code can be simplified into a `for` loop by verifying blank cells using the worksheet function `CountA`.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub CutRowsWithEmptyCells2()
    Dim wsIn As Worksheet, wsout As Worksheet
    Dim MyRange, lrowOut As Long
    Dim rowRange As Range, dataRange As Range
    Set wsIn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Customer Data")
    Set wsout = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Incomplete Data")
    Set MyRange = wsIn.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    For Each rowRange In MyRange.Rows
        If Application.CountA(rowRange) < rowRange.Cells.Count Then
            lrowOut = wsout.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
            rowRange.EntireRow.Copy wsout.Cells(lrowOut, 1)
            If dataRange Is Nothing Then
                Set dataRange = rowRange
            Else
                Set dataRange = Application.Union(dataRange, rowRange)
            End If
        End If
    Next rowRange
    If Not dataRange Is Nothing Then dataRange.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: fyi using Union to build a non-contiguous range does not scale well. The time taken to add another non-contiguous range to the target range increases with the square of the number of non-contiguous ranges already in the target range.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's spectacular. I'm going to try to fully understand your solutions now, starting by the <code>CountA</code> function, which really simplifies it.

It's weird to me that we don't need to <code>Set</code> <code>RowRange</code> to anything. What is the loop then iterating through? It's not cells, it's not rows, it's an unspecified Range, which seems weird to me.

Comment: `For Each rowRange In MyRange.Rows` will interate all rows in MyRange. You can think there are some invisible code. `Set rowRange = MyRange.Rows(1)` , `Set rowRange = MyRange.Rows(2)` ...

Comment: @chrisneilsen I have read your famous post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/10717999#10717999. But I'd like to know why it is time cosuming.

Comment: Hi @taller_ExcelHome.  I'm not sure what you're asking me.  Are you referring to Select, or my earlier comment about Union?

Comment: sorry. I am asking about Union.

Comment: For union performance see here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56573408/478884

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome As I mentioned in my first comment,  the time taken to add another range with Union depends on how many Areas (aka non-contiguous ranges) already exist in the target range. The time increases ws the square of the number of Areas. If you were to ask a Q about this, I could post my research...

Comment: @chrisneilsen Yes, that's what I was asking. Please share it. Thanks